# How to check if a git command, string of subcommands, or argument, is valid?

Tags: git, shell, parsing, command-line

When using git, I find myself mistyping git commands ***far too often***. I would like to create a tool for my shell that provides feedback on git commands, subcommands, and arguments, as I type them in.

For example, if I feed it the string

```
git checkout .
```

I would get no feedback or some kind of successful result, but if I instead fed it

```
git chcekout .
```

I may get some feedback to inform me that `chcekout` is not recognized as a valid command. I could then use this feedback to add some kind of display attribute to that token in my shell so that I could immediately see this before finishing, perhaps like

[image: Git chcekout error indicator.]

Does git provide some kind of parallel utility that allows for token preprocessing like this, with details on what kinds of issues are present in the command line?

Comment: Git doesn't, but some shells do. Bash in particular has *command completion*, which can be scripted. Other shells have stolen the concept as well; some may have fancied it up to do things like color particular words (I'd suspect zsh would do that).

Comment: Bash's command completion for git is provided by the `git-completion.bash` utility which is usually sourced in the bash rc. I was wondering if this concept had been extended to token preprocessing instead of just event-driven tab completion.

Comment: Yes - that's where my knowledge ends, though. The reason I suspect zsh might do this sort of thing is that some coworkers use it and it seems to have additional magic beyond bash-style completion. I'm already annoyed enough at bash completion for mis-completing various cases that I try not to use it in the first place. :-)

Comment: Zsh already has a kind of built-in preprocessing. This is taken advantage of by the git client via zsh's own `git-completion.zsh` utility, not so much that zsh has any built in extensions for git tokens.

Comment: `help.autoCorrect` may help in a different way. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-helpautoCorrect.